# To display data on a gridview in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, loops, gridview

I have two sets of dataset and the first dataset contains 20 number of records and the second one contains 21 number of records. When trying to retrieve the second dataset on a grid view, I'm not able to display the records but I can retrieve all the records from first dataset on a gridview. When I'm trying to retrieve the second dataset it is throwing an error like:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Post the code you had

Comment: int a = Int32.Parse(reals);
           DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
                
                dummy.Columns.Add("OrderNo");
                dummy.Columns.Add("InvoiceNo");


                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
                {
                    dummy.Rows.Add(
                    id["Results"][i]["OrderNo"].ToString(),
                   id["Results"][i]["InvoiceNo"].ToString());
                }
                
                GridView1.DataSource = dummy;
                GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Edit the question then post the code there. Also, Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Getting this error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index'
```

probably means exactly like it says, that your index is out of range of the dataset. if your index variable i is 22 for example, you will get this error since your datasets don't have a 22nd row. Have you tried debugging and checking whether i is larger than the size of your dataset at any point?

Also, please edit your question and add a code block like the other poster suggested. Without the code it's hard to pinpoint what exactly is going wrong.